# AJV: check if a property equals another property

Tags: node.js, ajv

By using `ajv`, how can I reference `foo` to validate that `bar` has the same value?

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});

var schema = {
  'properties': {
    'foo': { 'type': 'string', 'minLength': 3 },
    'bar': { 'type': 'string', ###HERE### },
  }
};

data = {
  'foo': 'abc',
  'bar': 'ab',
};

ajv.validate(schema, data);   // <-- should return false, foo !== bar
```

I've tried using (with similar variations):

```
...
'bar': { 'type': 'string', 'format': { '$data': 'foo' } },
...
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can:

```
var ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true, $data: true}); // for version >=5.0.0

var schema = {
  properties: {
    foo: { type: 'string', minLength: 3 },
    bar: { const: { $data: '1/foo' } },
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what `1/` means?

Comment: How to do not same as another field? For example, `foo` is not equal to `baz`.

Comment: @alayor -It's been a while here, but `1/` basically means "go up one level and check the property".

Answer (score 3):

@explorer, here it is

```
foo: {
    type: "string",
    not: {
        const: {
            $data: "1/baz"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `1/`?, `$data` is not the static content?